# maven の wagon:sshexec で、動作する最低限のサンプルはありますか

Tags: ssh, maven

maven でもって、サーバーに対して ssh 実行を行おうと考えました。少し調べたところ、

1. maven-exec-plugin でもって ssh するスクリプトを実行する
2. maven-antrun-plugin でもって、 ant で記述する
3. wagon-maven-plugin:sshexec でもって実行する

がある様子です。 Windows でも Ubuntu でも実行できたらうれしいので、 3 の sshexec プラグインを試してみようと考えました。

http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html に、最小限の利用方法のようなものは書いてありますが、 Windows でも Ubuntu でも、これを今現在動かせていません。

### 前提条件

- ssh -i PRIVATEKEY USER@HOST で、疎通はできる。 (Ubuntu で確認)

### 質問

上記の通り、 ssh 可能なサーバーがあったときに、ここに対して sshexec で helloworld をひとまず行いたいと考えているのですが、これを実現する最小限の、動作する pom.xml ないし設定はどうなりますでしょうか。ネットで検索しても、動作する設定例が発見できなかったので、質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結局、 maven-antrun-plugin を使った方がずっと楽だったので、こちらを利用することにしました。

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test</name>

  <properties>
    <my.ssh.key>/path/to/ssh/key</my.ssh.key>
    <my.target.host>host-name</my.target.host>
    <my.target.user>ssh-user-name</my.target.user>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>hello-world</id>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <taskdef name="sshexec"
                         classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec"
                         classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"
                />
                <sshexec host="${my.target.host}"
                         username="${my.target.user}"
                         keyfile="${my.ssh.key}"
                         command="echo hello"
                         trust="true"
                         />
                <!-- trust がないと、 known host 以外はエラーになる -->
              </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

上記 pom を配置したフォルダで、 `mvn antrun:run@hello-world` を実行することで、 ssh 実行ができていることを確認できます。